# Applying slimscroll to datatables

Tags: datatable, slimscroll

Am trying to apply the slimscroll for datatable. There is pre-defined vertical as well as horizontal bars for datatable.Is there any possibility to apply the slimscroll for datatable?
Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can apply slimscroll to datatable by adding below function in your datatable code

```
            "fnInitComplete":function(){
                $('.dataTables_scrollBody').slimscroll();
            },
```

Also check this out too 
[Can we apply SlimScroll or PerfectScrollbar plugin to jQuery Datatable default vertical scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031084/can-we-apply-slimscroll-or-perfectscrollbar-plugin-to-jquery-datatable-default-v#)

Comment: Very elegant :-)