# Can we apply SlimScroll or PerfectScrollbar plugin to jQuery Datatable default vertical scroll

Tags: datatable, datatables, scrollbar, datatables-1.10, perfect-scrollbar

I am using Datatable ver 1.10, I enable the vertical scrolling. now datatable showing window default scroll style.

Is it possible to change/implement some other scrollBar on datatable scrollbar? to make it more beautiful and fancy.

[image]

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26970544/1216451) at stackoverflow but it squeez the header.
also I want header and footer fixed position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is my working code

```
// when initialization is completed then apply scroll plugin
"fnInitComplete":function(){
    $('.dataTables_scrollBody').perfectScrollbar();
},

//apply scroll on this height
"scrollY": 450,

//on paginition page 2,3.. often scroll shown, so reset it and assign it again 
"fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
    $('.dataTables_scrollBody').perfectScrollbar('destroy').perfectScrollbar();
},
```

Comment: hi i is there any work around if i use colvis (the one that hide or show column) in my datatables? since if i horizontal scroll and then hide some column, it is not automatically aligned and show some blank column....